# Why am I receiving a Recursion error with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, geocode

I'm looking to geocode a large list of addresses using multiprocessing. I have the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import geocoder

addresses = ['New York City, NY','Austin, TX', 'Los Angeles, CA', 'Boston, MA'] # and on and on

def geocode_worker(address):
    return geocoder.arcgis(address)

def main_process():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    return pool.map(geocode_worker, addresses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_process()
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 470, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 599, in __getattr__
    if not self.ok:
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 536, in ok
    return len(self) > 0
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geocoder/base.py", line 422, in __len__
    return len(self._list)
```

The last 3 lines of the error are repeated over and over again, and then the last line of the traceback is:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: what's the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: The problem is likely in geocoder itself.  The code as shown is correct. I removed the geocoder dependency and it ran fine.

Comment: So does this just mean that the geocoder is incompatible with multiprocessing? Or is there something I can do to the geocoding process to make it work? When I try another geocoder (geopy) I receive a "Service Timed out error"

Comment: it means you should [edit] your question to include the traceback. We can only speculate otherwise.

Comment: It also means making a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, I've edited my original question to include the error traceback.

Comment: The problem happens when `multiprocessing` tries to unpickle the results that were returned by `geocoder.arcgis` in the main process. There's a bug in `geocoder` that causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, the bug is that the objects returned by `geocoder.arcgis` just aren't picklable. You can reproduce it by just do `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(<object returned by geocoder.arcgs()>)`. The simplest workaround would be to pull whatever data you need from what gets returned, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `ArcgisQuery` object returned by `geocoder` is not picklable - or rather, it's not unpicklable. The unpickle process hits an infinite loop due to its use of `__getattr__`, which internally tries to access `self.ok`, which eventually relies on `self._list` to be defined, which is not defined while unpickling, because it is only defined in `__init__`, and [`__init__` is not called while unpickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__). Since it's not defined, it tries to use `__getattr__` to find it, which tries to access `self.ok` again, and creates the infinite loop.

You can work around this by not passing the `ArcgisQuery` object itself between the worker process and your main process, and instead pass just its underlying `__dict__`. Then, rebuild the `ArcgisQuery` objects in your main process:

```py
import multiprocessing
import geocoder
from geocoder.arcgis import ArcgisQuery

addresses = ['New York City, NY','Austin, TX', 'Los Angeles, CA', 'Boston, MA'] # and on and on

def geocode_worker(address):
    out = geocoder.arcgis(address)
    return out.__dict__ # Only return the object's __dict__

def main_process():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    l = pool.map(geocode_worker, addresses)
    out = []
    for d in l:
        q = ArcgisQuery(d['location'])  # location is a required constructor arg
        q.__dict__.update(d)  # Load the rest of our state into the new object
        out.append(q)
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main_process())
```

If you don't actually need the whole `ArcgisQuery` object, and only need some parts of it, you could also just return those from the worker processes, to avoid the need for this hack.

For what it's worth, it looks like `geocoder` could fix its pickling problem by implementing `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` on ArcgisQuery or its base class, like this:

```py
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't need the whole object so when I just called on part of it, it worked perfectly.